# Using MAX() in sub query without GROUP BY

Tags: mysql

I'm doing pratice work for a class and I have the following schema to work with:

```
Project (Projectid, Milestoneid, dateBegin, dateEnd)
Milestone (Milestoneid, MilestoneName, MilestoneDesc)
```

I need to output the Projectid, with the Milestonename and Milestonedesc of the latest milestone for each project (latest milestone for each project is the highest Milestoneid for a given projectid)

I was given the following clues: "You want to find Max value of Milestoneid. you must not use GROUP BY."
I know I have to use the MAX aggregate, but I must not use 'GROUP BY', which is where I'm lost.
Obviously I have to use MAX in a subquery, for something like this:

```
SELECT Project.Projectid, Milestone.Milestonename, Milestone.Milestonedesc 
FROM Project p, Milestone m 
WHERE m.Milestoneid = (
SELECT MAX(m.Milestoneid) 
FROM Milestone m 
WHERE
)
```

I'm at a loss as to how query the table to get a MAX id for each Projectid without group by.

If anyone has any pointers it would greatly help me understand this part of SQL I'm unfamiliar with.

Thanks

Comment: Not a requirement, but it was how I figured I would get my result.

Comment: Sorry about it, I edited to make it clearer, also I added the clues I was given. It seems MAX is a requirement after all.

Comment: It's ridiculous that a milestone_id would be in a `project` table, but anyway...

Comment: the 'project' table is used to record every milestones the projects achieved, and when. the table could be named 'projectstatus' or something, but its purpose is the same.

Comment: That would be the `project_milestone` table. The `project` table would record basic project particulars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A small tweak to your query offers another solution.  The request says not to use `group by`, but you can have a correlated subquery without `group by`:

```
SELECT p.Projectid, m.Milestonename, m.Milestonedesc 
FROM Project p JOIN
     Milestone m 
     p.Milestoneid = m.Milestoneid
WHERE m.Milestoneid = (SELECT MAX(p2.Milestoneid) 
                       FROM Project p2
                       WHERE p2.ProjectId = p.ProjectId
                      )
```

Comment: This works perfectly! And even better, I understand the equation. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the MAX keyword is a red herring. Anyway, here's one solution (incomplete)...

```
SELECT x.* 
  FROM project x
  LEFT 
  JOIN project y
    ON y.project_id = x.project_id

    -- any other JOINs go here

   AND y.milestoneid < x.milestoneid
 WHERE y.projectid IS NULL

    -- any other conditions go here;
```

Comment: Since there are a variable number of distinct project_id I don't know how I can figure out how many joins I will need. Is there a way using `COUNT(DISTINCT project_id)` ?